# How mock new instance with mockito

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I have this class:

```
package br.com.lumera.notificato.api.central.o;

import br.com.lumera.cec.modelmapper.mapping.vo.AcessoCentral;
import br.com.lumera.cec.modelmapper.model.Cartorio;
import br.com.lumera.cec.modelmapper.model.EmailRequestVO;
import br.com.lumera.cec.modelmapper.model.pedido.*;
import br.com.lumera.notificato.api.central.Central;
import br.com.lumera.notificato.api.central.Filtro;
import br.com.lumera.notificato.api.central.FiltroOnr;
import br.com.lumera.notificato.api.central.exceptions.CentralException;
import br.com.lumera.notificato.api.exception.ValidationException;
import br.com.lumera.notificato.api.service.EmailService;
import br.com.lumera.notificato.api.service.ServicoService;
import br.com.lumera.notificato.api.util.Utils;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.certidao.CertidaoFacade;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.certidao.ONREnvioAnexoException;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.certidao.model.PedidoCertidao;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.certidao.model.StatusCertidao;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.certidao.model.TipoCertidao;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.certidao.model.TipoCobranca;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.exception.ONRDevolverCertidaoException;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.exception.ONRFinalizarRespostaCertidaoException;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.exception.ONRInformarCustasCertidaoException;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.login.exception.ONRLoginInvalidoException;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.login.exception.ONRUsuarioInativoException;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.login.ws.LoginConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class CentralO implements Central {

    @Autowired
    private PedidoCertidaoOMapper pedidoCertidaoOMapper;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper;
    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;
    private CertidaoFacade certidaoFacade;

    protected CertidaoFacade preencherDadosAcesso(AcessoCentral acessoCentral) throws CentralException {
        try {
            return certidaoFacade.login(LoginConfig.builder()
                    .chave(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("chave"))
                    .cn(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("cn"))
                    .cpf(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("cpf"))
                    .email(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("email"))
                    .idParceiro(Integer.parseInt(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("idParceiro")))
                    .issuer(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("issuer"))
                    .publickey(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("publicKey"))
                    .serialnumber(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("serialNumber"))
                    .validUntil(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("validUntil"))
                    .build());
        } catch (OUsuarioInativoException e) {
            throw new CentralException("Usuário inativo", e.getMessage());
        } catch (OLoginInvalidoException e) {
            throw new CentralException("Login inválido", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    
    @Override
    public void enviarCustas(AcessoCentral acessoCentral, DadosCentral dadosCentral, BigDecimal valor) throws CentralException {
        try {
            log.debug("Pedido {} deve enviar valores: {}", dadosCentral.getIdentificacao(), valor);
            preencherDadosAcesso(acessoCentral).informarCustasCertidao(dadosCentral.getIdentificacao(), valor);
        } catch (OInformarCustasCertidaoException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

   

}
```

and this test class that works fine.

```
package br.com.lumera.notificato.api.central.o;

import br.com.lumera.cec.modelmapper.mapping.vo.AcessoCentral;
import br.com.lumera.cec.modelmapper.model.pedido.DadosCentral;
import br.com.lumera.notificato.api.central.Central;
import br.com.lumera.notificato.api.central.exceptions.CentralException;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.certidao.CertidaoFacade;
import br.com.lumera.onr.wsoficio.exception.ONRInformarCustasCertidaoException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CentralOTest {

    @Mock
    CertidaoFacade certidaoFacade;
    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    CentralO centralO;
    AcessoCentral acessoCentral;


    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("chave","1" );
        map.put("cn","1");
        map.put("cpf","1");
        map.put("email","1");
        map.put("idParceiro","1");
        map.put("issuer","1");
        map.put("publicKey","1");
        map.put("serialNumber","1");
        map.put("validUntil","1");
        acessoCentral = AcessoCentral.builder()
                .nome(Central.CENTRAL.O.name())
                .dadosAcesso(map)
                .build();


        given(certidaoFacade.login(any())).willReturn(certidaoFacade);

    }


    @Test
    void enviarCustas() throws OInformarCustasCertidaoException, CentralException {
        DadosCentral dadosCentral = DadosCentral.builder().identificacao("S2134351313153").build();
        willDoNothing().given(certidaoFacade).informarCustasCertidao(dadosCentral.getIdentificacao(), BigDecimal.ZERO);
        centralO.enviarCustas(acessoCentral, dadosCentral, BigDecimal.ZERO);
    }

}
```

But now I need to change in my CentraO class from this:

```
private CertidaoFacade certidaoFacade;// = new CertidaoFacade();

    protected CertidaoFacade preencherDadosAcesso(AcessoCentral acessoCentral) throws CentralException {
        try {
            return certidaoFacade.login(LoginConfig.builder()
                    .chave(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("chave"))
                    .cn(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("cn"))
                    .cpf(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("cpf"))
                    .email(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("email"))
                    .idParceiro(Integer.parseInt(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("idParceiro")))
                    .issuer(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("issuer"))
                    .publickey(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("publicKey"))
                    .serialnumber(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("serialNumber"))
                    .validUntil(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("validUntil"))
                    .build());
        } catch (ONRUsuarioInativoException e) {
            throw new CentralException("Usuário inativo", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ONRLoginInvalidoException e) {
            throw new CentralException("Login inválido", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

to this:

```
    protected CertidaoFacade preencherDadosAcesso(AcessoCentral acessoCentral) throws CentralException {
        try {
            return new CertidaoFacade().login(LoginConfig.builder()
                    .chave(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("chave"))
                    .cn(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("cn"))
                    .cpf(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("cpf"))
                    .email(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("email"))
                    .idParceiro(Integer.parseInt(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("idParceiro")))
                    .issuer(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("issuer"))
                    .publickey(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("publicKey"))
                    .serialnumber(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("serialNumber"))
                    .validUntil(acessoCentral.getDadosAcesso().get("validUntil"))
                    .build());
        } catch (ONRUsuarioInativoException e) {
            throw new CentralException("Usuário inativo", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ONRLoginInvalidoException e) {
            throw new CentralException("Login inválido", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

but with this change I cannot mock the new instace of CertidaoFacade. It's possible to still using all my mocked (when) with this new instance?

Comment: 1. Why (this) need has appeared? (`new ...` is also possible..at least with powermock), but maybe you *want* something more like: `(get)certidaoFacade()` (custom method, (scoped bean or similar..)), which would also be easier to mock/spy/inject?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-is-my-class-not-using-my-mock-in-unit-test